# Compilation error when using @Transactional with propagation attribute

Tags: spring-boot, transactional

I developed a spring data jpa program using [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorial. Then modified it by adding a new class/method to test spring's @Transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional
public void txnMethod() {
    repository.save(new Customer("First Customer",""));
    repository.save(new Customer("Second Customer",""));
    ...
}
```

The above code compiled and executed correctly.
Then I modified the code to explictly set propagation mode as shown below, but this gives me a compilation error - *"The attribute propagation is undefined for the annotation type Transactional"*

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void txnMethod() {
    repository.save(new Customer("First Customer",""));
    repository.save(new Customer("Second Customer",""));
    ...
}
```

How can I specify the propagation mode explicitly ?
Below are the dependencies in build.gradle. Am using spring boot version 1.2.1.RELEASE

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")   
    compile("com.h2database:h2")                                      
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")   
}
```

Comment: Is your `@Transactional` `javax.transaction.Transactional` or `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`?  The later is found in `spring-tx.jar` and supports `Propagation`, which is also found in `spring-tx.jar`.

Comment: The @Transactional is *import javax.transaction.Transactional*

Comment: There is the problem.  You need to use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Comment: @Manish - Please post the answer, so that I can accept it formally.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When working with applications that have a direct or transitive dependency on Spring Data, two classes with the name `@Transactional` are available on the compile-time classpath.  One of these is `javax.persistence.Transactional` and the other one is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.  It is the later class that must be used for declarative transaction management with Spring.  The enumeration `Propagation` is also supported only by the later.  The former supports a different enumeration called `TxType`.

Do ensure that the `@Transactional` you are applying is of the type `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` as IDEs sometimes add an import for `javax.persistence.Transactional` while the user is typing `@Transactional`.  Then, attempting to add `Propagation` to the annotation fails because `javax.persistence.Transactional` does not support this enumeration.

Comment: Thanks. Silly mistake.